# Sidemenu on dynamic contentpage is not loading

Tags: php, sql, .htaccess

I got a simple dynamic content page build like this:

.htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteBase /_extern/website/

#Indexes uitzetten
Options -Indexes

#website
RewriteRule     ^(.*).html content.php?alias=$1 [L]
```

Here I get the data for the contentpage

content.php:

```
//  content
    $content        = "SELECT * FROM `db_content` WHERE alias = '".$_GET['alias']."' ";
    $contentcon         = $conn->query($content);
    $contentcr          = array();
    while ($contentcr[]     = $contentcon->fetch_array());
```

And then I can echo the data inside a foreach or in other ways.

I am using two tables, db_content and db_categories both of which have a column named `alias`. What I am trying to do is get all the content pages that belong to a category and show them in a side menu.

So I made this query:

```
//  Pages
$page           = "SELECT con.title, con.alias, con.images, con.introtext
                       FROM db_content con
                       LEFT JOIN db_categories cat ON con.catid = cat.id
                       WHERE cat.alias = 'info' AND con.state = 1 ORDER BY `ordering` DESC";
$pagecon            = $conn->query($page);
$pagecr         = array();
while ($pagecr[]    = $pagecon->fetch_array());
```

With `info` being an alias of a category. If I program it like this, it works, but only for the category info, I want it to work for every category, using only a single content.php

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Adjust to `LEFT JOIN db_categories cat ON con.catid = cat.id AND cat.alias = 'info' WHERE con.state = 1` to get true left join behavior. (As it is now you get regular inner join result...) But I can't really understand what the purpose is...

Comment: @jarlh Thanks but that is not what I am looking for, this still means that `info` is "hardcoded" in the query.

Comment: It wasn't really meant to be *the*answer, just a correction.

Comment: @jarlh Alright thanks anyway. The purpose of the query is to get all articles beloning to a category. But only when a category page is opened. For examle a content page has alias `info`, then on that page I want all pages with category `info` to be echoed in a side menu.